# mysql.data.dll connection timing out

Tags: mysql, powershell, connection, timeout

I'm using `mysql.data.dll` with `powershell` (v2) to make a connection to a my MySQL Database. The connection string looks like this:

```
$connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=" + $MySQLPort + ";uid=" + $MySQLUser + ";pwd=" + $MySQLPass + ";database=" + $MySQLDatabase + ";Pooling=FALSE" 
    try 
    {
        $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = $connStr
        $conn.Open()
    }
```

It connects fine, but when I run a query that takes more than a few seconds it times out. 
Running the query directly on the database is fine (despite taking apx 40 seconds to run), so I assume that there is a timeout associated with this connection causing the problem.
Is there a way therefore that I can tell this connection not to timeout for 60 seconds.

Comment: it's powershell

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with connecting a Python virtual environment with MySQL.

Turns out I needed a self-contained Python driver for communicating with MySQL servers.

Did some research, and found this:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

I gather that you need the **mysql** plugin:

> php5-mysql

**Good** you're using PowerShell: *both windows and linux commands work*.

What you need can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Or run PowerShell as administrator (right click on top of the icon in the start menu) and use:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the correct answer, but it seems to have worked.

I added `default command timeout=180;` to the end of the connection string. So I now have:

```
$connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=" + $MySQLPort + ";uid=" + $MySQLUser + ";pwd=" + $MySQLPass + ";database=" + $MySQLDatabase + ";Pooling=FALSE; default command timeout=180" 
    try 
    {
        $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = $connStr
        $conn.Open()
    }
```